# Error with EUtilsSummary in RISmed package: 'length = 4' coercion issue

Tags: r

I'm encountering an issue while using the RISmed (v:2.3.0) package in R(v:4.3.2), specifically with the EUtilsSummary function. I've followed the instructions provided, but I'm getting the following error:

```
Error in any(is.na(WhichArgs)) || sapply(WhichArgs, length) > 1 : 
  'length = 4' in coercion to 'logical(1)'
```

Here's the code snippet causing the problem:

```
library(RISmed)
query <- "Runs of Homozygosity"
ngs_search <- EUtilsSummary(query, type = "esearch", db = "pubmed", mindate = 1999, maxdate = 2023, retmax = 30000)
```

Can someone help me understand and resolve this issue? I'm relatively new to RISmed, and any guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a problem with 4.3 R version

https://github.com/skoval/RISmed/issues/39

maybe for now, try runing this in older versions